# What is the process of combining vectors into a matrix called?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, terminology

> What is the process of combining vectors into a matrix called?

My question is not how or why to do this.  My question is, "What is this process called?"

For example, if we need a solution for a system of linear equations, one method is to represent the unknowns as column vectors and then join those column vectors into a single matrix.  One way to describe it might be to say "indexing" an array but I'm looking for a formal terminology.  Ultimately, I'd like to know how to represent this in a generalized form.

Essentially, I'm asking how to describe and formally write something like this:

$$
\begin{equation}
\vec v_1=\left(\begin{array}{c} X_1 \\ Y_1 \\ Z_1 \end{array}\right), \vec v_2=\left(\begin{array}{c} X_2 \\ Y_2 \\ Z_2 \end{array}\right) \rightarrow M=\left(\begin{array}{cc} X_1 & X_2 \\ Y_1 & Y_2 \\ Z_1 & Z_2 \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We call a matrix produced by concatenation of two appropriately sized matrices (not necessarily vectors) an [*augmented*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) matrix. To emphasize that we formed such a matrix in this way, we might write (continuing the given example)
$$M = \left(\begin{array}{c|c}{\bf v}_1 & {\bf v}_2\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c|c}X_1 & X_2 \\ Y_1 & Y_2 \\ Z_1 & Z_2 \\ \end{array}\right) .$$
Depending on context, I might not use this term when concatenating more than two vectors, that is, when forming for vectors ${\bf w}_1 , \ldots, {\bf w}_r$ the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}{\bf w}_1 & \cdots & {\bf w}_r\end{array}\right) .$$ (In this case I would generally omit the bars, $\vert$.)

Comment: *That* was the term I was missing! :)

Comment: In my experience, it's also commonly written without the bar as $M = (  \mathbf{v}_1 \ \mathbf{v}_2  )$.

Comment: Yes, I only meant to introduce the alternative notation (hence "might write"). In general if you're forming a matrix out of several vectors, usually one doesn't write with bars. The bar is commonly used when one of the matrices has $> 1$ column, e.g., when one forms the augmented matrix $({\bf A} \,|\, {\bf b})$ encoding a linear system ${\bf A} {\bf x} = {\bf b}$.

Comment: "Augmented." Excellent!  Thank you.